# How do I get a list of files deleted from ext4 filesystem ...?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, data-recovery

I recently accidentally deleted some files on an ext4 partition with `rm -rf`. I haven't overwritten the space, and have a copy of both the journal and the whole filesystem (via `dd`) from shortly after the error.

I also have the files backed up, however I deleted only a small portion of my backed files. I estimate around 7000 files were deleted out of over 2 million. To restore everything would entail an over 1TB download, which I want to avoid.

What I need is a list of the file *names* so I can selectively restore them if needed.

If I use `ext4magic` on the drive it gives me the following:

[image]

So it seems it can "see" the 7k files that were deleted.

However, if I then try to list the deleted files with:

`sudo ./ext4magic /media/backup/icebox.image -a 1592528436 -l`

It gives the following output:

```
Filesystem in use: /media/backup/icebox.image

Using  internal Journal at Inode 8
Activ Time after  : Fri Jun 19 02:00:36 2020
Activ Time before : Thu Jun 25 09:28:36 2020
Inode 2 is allocated
Warning: error-NR 2133571456 can not found file: /
ext4magic : EXIT_SUCCESS
```

I can mount the filesystem with `mount /media/backup/icebox.image /media/tmp` and view the remaining files just fine.

Does anyone know how I can list the files...?

Also happy to try a different tool if there is something more effective than `ext4magic`.

Comment: Can't you just get the current list of files and the list of files from your backup and compare those?

Comment: There's a significant chance the file names are just gone. Similar to terdon's comment, could you use a tool like [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) to simply restore the backup?  Are you deliberately trying to avoid restoring files modified since the backup?

Comment: @terdon Annoyingly, its' an online backup (Backblaze), and for some reason they are unable or unwilling to supply a full list of backed up files. If they could do that, the problem would be solved as I could just diff against what I have.

Comment: @PhilipCouling yeah, that is for B2, which is what I'm switching to. My current backups are with Backblaze "Personal" which just has a web API and Mac client app.

Comment: @PhilipCouling OK, to be clear. B2 has a web API, which I'm aware of. Backblaze personal only has a web UI (pictured here: https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/217665888-How-to-Create-a-Restore-from-Your-Backblaze-Backup)

Comment: @PhilipCouling as far as I can tell, the whole point of this question is to avoid downloading everything: "*To restore everything would entail an over 1TB download, which I want to avoid.*". And that's understandable since it would take a very, very long time both to download and to do anything with the downloaded data.

Comment: @terdon yeah having gone through and looked at the UI I think I go back to my earlier (deleted) comment of: it's time to change backup provider.  Inability to list files is a pretty big miss.  I suspect they've made this decision to try to get users to pay out of "send me my files on a hard drive".